# Error on creating Eclipse workspace for gradle

Tags: java, gradle, forge

I am trying to create a workspace using the command "gradlew setupDecompWorkspace", I have downloaded a zip from the forge website for 1.8.9-11.15.1.2318 as the mdk version, unzipped it into a folder and now in that folder I am running the command, however it returns this error message:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MCMods'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.1-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         :MCMods:unspecified
      > Could not resolve net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.1-SNAPSHOT.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/2.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/2.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > peer not authenticated
      > Could not resolve net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.1-SNAPSHOT.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/2.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/2.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > peer not authenticated
```

I have downloaded the version Java SE Development Kit 8u5 from this website: https://www.oracle.com/uk/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html, any ideas why it doesnt work? And yes I have put them into %JAVA_HOME% and also Path

**My build.gradle file with settings:**

```
// For those who want the bleeding edge
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge'

/*
// for people who want stable - not yet functional for MC 1.8.8 - we require the forgegradle 2.1 snapshot
plugins {
    id "net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge" version "2.0.2"
}
*/
version = "1.0"
group= "com.yourname.modid" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = "modid"

minecraft {
    version = "1.8.9-11.15.1.2318-1.8.9"
    runDir = "run"
    
    // the mappings can be changed at any time, and must be in the following format.
    // snapshot_YYYYMMDD   snapshot are built nightly.
    // stable_#            stables are built at the discretion of the MCP team.
    // Use non-default mappings at your own risk. they may not allways work.
    // simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
    mappings = "stable_20"
    // makeObfSourceJar = false // an Srg named sources jar is made by default. uncomment this to disable.
}

dependencies {
    // you may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs
    // or you may define them like so..
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version"
      
    // real examples
    //compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
    //compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

    // the 'provided' configuration is for optional dependencies that exist at compile-time but might not at runtime.
    //provided 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // the deobf configurations:  'deobfCompile' and 'deobfProvided' are the same as the normal compile and provided,
    // except that these dependencies get remapped to your current MCP mappings
    //deobfCompile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'
    //deobfProvided 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // for more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}

processResources
{
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'
                
        // replace version and mcversion
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }
        
    // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to use Android Studio or intelliJ IDEA IDE.

Comment: `> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/2.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > peer not authenticated` As you can see you need a credentials to some private minecraft repository, with additional dependencies. More likely you should add some settings file with creds to this repo.

Comment: Unrelated: Why go with Java 8? Java 21 came out in fall 2023...

Comment: @Robert i read on multiple sources you have to use Java 8 for this version of Forge. I might be wrong

Comment: @VictorGubin Any idea why that happens? I edited the post with my settings in build.gradle, if that is what you meant

Comment: @Karafakeu IT happens because of this
`maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }` See [flowing manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html) Some Ukrainian speaking Maincraft mod community consider it as a known issue and recommending to use https://maven.minecraftforge.net/ as URL instead of files.minecraftforge.net

Comment: @Karafakeu As well as same thing recommended at https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/99909-cant-open-new-project-and-build-old-one/

Comment: @VictorGubin yes, this works. I found the exact thing, but didnt get to the part that you mentioned. Thanks a lot!